# Group by json array using key and value from json itself android

Tags: android, json

I need help in making the result in group-by format through json array. 
Below is my json array and I need to group-by records under "main" using json keys + values i.e. item_name and heat.

```
{
"results": {
        "main": [
            {
                "id": "123",
                "item_id": "234",
                "entry": "1",
                "item_name": "ASW 2-",
                "event_type": "2-",
                "heat": "Heat #1"
            },
            {
                "id": "678",
                "item_id": "789",
                "entry": "1",
                "item_name": "ASW 2-",
                "event_type": "2-",
                "heat": "Heat #2"
            }]
}}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to group the array by the same key and value i.e. by using event_name and heat from above json data and show data accordingly in listview

Comment: I think you have to store data in database then try to get data from database as per your requirement.

Comment: I can't use database here as I have to use web-services only.

Comment: It seems your issue is of writing query at server side. If so then it's not related to `Android` some how.

Comment: If you have done the parsing then you can serialize the object/array and save it in the preferences or in db itself

Comment: I have done parsing but never done grouping before in android (except sqlite).. without grouping all the data occurs in listview without any problem. Can anyone please help to group 2 fields.